# Codility Fish (queue) programming challenge

Tags: java, programming-challenge, stack, queue

Today I have attempted a Codility exercise "Fish" (https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/7-stacks_and_queues/fish/), and I have to say I found it to be:
1) Not necessarily "easy" as implied by the page, AND
2) Quite satisfying to figure out in the end.
Below the text of the challenge:

> You are given two non-empty arrays A and B consisting of N integers.
>   Arrays A and B represent N voracious fish in a river, ordered
>   downstream along the flow of the river.
>
> The fish are numbered from 0 to N − 1. If P and Q are two fish and P <
>   Q, then fish P is initially upstream of fish Q. Initially, each fish
>   has a unique position.
>
> Fish number P is represented by A[P] and B[P]. Array A contains the
>   sizes of the fish. All its elements are unique. Array B contains the
>   directions of the fish. It contains only 0s and/or 1s, where:
>
> - 0 represents a fish flowing upstream,
> - 1 represents a fish flowing downstream.
>
> If two fish move in opposite directions and there are no other
>   (living) fish between them, they will eventually meet each other. Then
>   only one fish can stay alive − the larger fish eats the smaller one.
>   More precisely, we say that two fish P and Q meet each other when P <
>   Q, B[P] = 1 and B[Q] = 0, and there are no living fish between them.
>   After they meet:
>
> - If A[P] > A[Q] then P eats Q, and P will still be flowing downstream,
> - If A[Q] > A[P] then Q eats P, and Q will still be flowing upstream.
>
> We assume that all the fish are flowing at the same speed. That is,
>   fish moving in the same direction never meet. The goal is to calculate
>   the number of fish that will stay alive.

My solution is a bit playful, and I was wondering if anyone could have a look and let me know if this is a correct way of solving this problem. All comments will be appreciated.

````
import java.util.ArrayDeque;

// you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
// System.out.println("this is a debug message");

class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A, int[] B) {

        ArrayDeque<Fish> safetyPool = new ArrayDeque<Fish>();
        ArrayDeque<Fish> activePool = new ArrayDeque<Fish>();

        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            activePool.offer(Fish.cFish(A[i], B[i]));
        }

        while(!activePool.isEmpty()) {
            // System.out.println(safetyPool + " " + activePool);
            Fish safeFish = safetyPool.peekLast();
            Fish swimmingFish = activePool.peekFirst();

            if (safeFish != null) {
                if (safeFish.dir == 1) {
                    if (safeFish.dir != swimmingFish.dir) {
                        if (safeFish.att > swimmingFish.att) {
                            activePool.removeFirst();
                        } else {
                            safetyPool.removeLast();
                        }
                    } else {
                        safetyPool.offer(activePool.pollFirst());
                    }
                } else {
                    safetyPool.offer(activePool.pollFirst());
                }
            } else {
                safetyPool.offer(activePool.pollFirst());
            }
        }
        return safetyPool.size();
    }
}

class Fish {
    public int att;
    public int dir;

    public Fish(int att, int dir) {
        this.att = att;
        this.dir = dir;
    }

    public static Fish cFish(int att, int dir) {
        return new Fish(att, dir);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Fish(att: %d, dir: %d)", att, dir);
    }
}
```
````

Comment: Welcome to Code Review, I edited your post adding the text of the challenge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have some suggestions.

1. When declaring variable that has inheritance, uses the interface in the left declaration part; this will make the code easier to refactor.

**Before**

```java
ArrayDeque<Fish> safetyPool = new ArrayDeque<Fish>();
ArrayDeque<Fish> activePool = new ArrayDeque<Fish>();
```

**After**

```java
Deque<Fish> safetyPool = new ArrayDeque<Fish>();
Deque<Fish> activePool = new ArrayDeque<Fish>();
```

2. When using the diamond operators with variables, declared the type in the left side, the right one will become optional; since it's declared in the variable side.

```java
Deque<Fish> safetyPool = new ArrayDeque<>();
Deque<Fish> activePool = new ArrayDeque<>();
```

3. To remove the `Arrow Code` in the while, I suggest that you read the blog post made by Jeff Atwood [`Flattening Arrow Code`](https://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/). In my opinion, it's the best way to get rid this kind of code.

The logic contained in the while can be refactored.

```java
while (!activePool.isEmpty()) {
   Fish safeFish = safetyPool.peekLast();
   Fish swimmingFish = activePool.peekFirst();

   if (safeFish == null || safeFish.dir != 1 || safeFish.dir == swimmingFish.dir) {
      safetyPool.offer(activePool.pollFirst());
      continue;
   }

   if (safeFish.att > swimmingFish.att) {
      activePool.removeFirst();
   } else {
      safetyPool.removeLast();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Doi9t, I really appreciate your comments. I am still new to Java, and have seen the approach from paragraphs 1&2 of your answer in other spots, but could never figure out why it was being done this way. Now I know, that this is to allow us an easier access to polymorphic features downstream from the declarations.
Paragraph 3 is pure gold as well - I am one of these programmers, who sharpens the arrow head quite a lot at times. The article you linked really helps with change of my habits. A+ answer! :)